# Using Asp.net core security in MVC5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, owin

We are using Adal as authentication library but we would like to use the policy functionality in Asp.Net Core security in our MVC5 application. The idea is to compile the Asp.Net Core library to .NET 4.6. This works! However, now I need to click the authentication things in my owin application.

Just adding the AuthorizeAttribute from the library doesn't work, it is not executed.

I have also read about the ported version from P. Schaeflein, but I would preffer to use the libraries provided by Microsoft.

Anyone an idea how to get this working?

Answer (score 1):

Asp.net Core / .net core is a total rewrite of asp.net framework and the way it work is very different. For example Asp.net Core is most made around a Dependency Injection. So moving part of a framework that made for Asp.net Core to Asp.net MVC 4.6 made not work and would have to be rebuild to work with Asp.net MVC 4.6.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Would it be a possibility to replace the full security library in MVC with the security library from .Net core. compiled to .NET 4.6?

Comment: Asp.net Core framework will run on .net 4.6 but Asp.net MVC 4.6  framework is different, sorry for the error. Asp.net Core  security library would need some or lot of changed to work with Asp.net MVC 4.6 framework. It would be best to Asp.net Core.   here the library https://github.com/aspnet/Security